# Multiselect to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, multi-select

I have a form with a multiselect to be saved to MySQL, but I can't save this select.
Thanks!

```
<select class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" id="id_vendedor"   multiple name="vendedor[]">
<?php
    $sql_vendedor=mysqli_query($con,"select * from users order by lastname");
    while ($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_vendedor)){
        $id_vendedor=$rw["user_id"];
        $nombre_vendedor=$rw["firstname"]." ".$rw["lastname"];
        if ($id_vendedor==$_SESSION['user_id']){
            $selected="selected";
        } else {
            $selected="";
        }
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id_vendedor?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $nombre_vendedor?></option>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean can't save? Is each option tag not displaying properly? Show us the errors you are getting.

Comment: The selected values will be in the array `$_POST['vendedor']`. You should be able to loop over the array to save them all in the database.

Comment: This select, now, save one values, but I need save two or more. Thanks!